# Slidebar não funciona

Tags: javascript, html5

Boa tarde!

Então, eu tenho um sliderbar na minha página, só que ele não está funcionando e não estou encontrando o error. Segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="{S_CONTENT_DIRECTION}" id="min-width" lang="{L_LANG_HTML}" xml:lang="{L_LANG_HTML}" {NAMESPACE_FB_LIKE} {NAMESPACE_FB} {NAMESPACE_BBCODE}>
<head>
   <title>{SITENAME_TITLE}{PAGE_TITLE}</title>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset={S_CONTENT_ENCODING}" />
   <meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript" />
   <meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css" />
   <!-- BEGIN switch_compat_meta -->
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE={switch_compat_meta.VERSION}" />
   <!-- END switch_compat_meta -->
   <!-- BEGIN switch_canonical_url -->
   <link rel="canonical" href="{switch_canonical_url.CANONICAL_URL}" />
   <!-- END switch_canonical_url -->
   {META_FAVICO}
   {META}
   {META_FB_LIKE}
   <meta name="title" content="{SITENAME_TITLE}{PAGE_TITLE}" />
   {T_HEAD_STYLESHEET}
   {CSS}
   <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="/improvedsearch.xml" title="{SITENAME}" />
   <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="{URL_BOARD_DIRECTORY}/search/improvedsearch.xml" title="{SEARCH_FORUMS}" />
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="{JS_DIR}{L_LANG}.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://www.fg-coding.net/15677.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.fg-coding.net/h59-"></script>
        <script src="http://www.fg-coding.net/16703.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.fg-coding.net/17729.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.fg-coding.net/11639.js"></script>      
        <script src="http://www.fg-coding.net/21211.js"></script>      
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/menueffect/script.js"></script>
   <!-- BEGIN switch_fb_login -->
   <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/{switch_fb_login.FB_LOCAL}/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="{switch_fb_login.JS_FB_LOGIN}" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <!-- END switch_fb_login -->

   <!-- BEGIN switch_ticker -->
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{JS_DIR}jquery/ticker/ticker.css" />
   <script src="{JS_DIR}jquery/ticker/ticker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <!-- END switch_ticker -->

   <!-- BEGIN switch_ticker_new -->
   <script src="{JS_DIR}jquery/jcarousel/jquery.jcarousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
      /* Definir le sens de direction en fonction du panneau admin */
      var tickerDirParam = "{switch_ticker.DIRECTION}";
      var slid_vert = false;
      var auto_dir = 'next';
      var h_perso = parseInt({switch_ticker.HEIGHT});

      switch( tickerDirParam )
      {
         case 'top' :
            slid_vert = true;
            break;

         case 'left':
            break;

         case 'bottom':
            slid_vert = true;
            auto_dir = 'prev';
            break;

         case 'right':
            auto_dir = 'prev';
            break;

         default:
            slid_vert = true;
      }

      $(document).ready(function() {

         var width_max = $('ul#fa_ticker_content').width();
         var width_item = Math.floor(width_max / {switch_ticker.SIZE});

         if (width_max > 0)
         {
            $('#fa_ticker_content').css('display','block');

            $('ul#fa_ticker_content li').css('float','left').css('list-style','none').width(width_item).find('img').each(function () {
               if ($(this).width() > width_item)
               {
               var ratio      = $(this).width() / width_item;
               var new_height = Math.round($(this).height() / ratio);
               $(this).height(new_height).width(width_item);
               }
            });

            if (slid_vert)
            {
               var height_max = h_perso;

               $('ul#fa_ticker_content li').each( function () {
                  if ($(this).height() > height_max)
                  {
                     height_max = $(this).height();
                  }
               } );

               $('ul#fa_ticker_content').width(width_item).height(height_max).css('marginLeft','auto').css('marginRight','auto');
               $('ul#fa_ticker_content li').height(height_max);
            }

            $('#fa_ticker_content').jcarousel({
                  vertical: slid_vert,
               wrap: 'circular',
               auto: {switch_ticker.STOP_TIME},
               auto_direction: auto_dir,
            scroll: 1,
            size: {switch_ticker.SIZE},
            height_max: height_max,
            animation: {switch_ticker.SPEED}
            });
         }
         else
         {
            $('ul#fa_ticker_content li:not(:first)').css('display','none');
            $('ul#fa_ticker_content li:first').css('list-style','none').css('text-align','center');
         }
      });
   //]]>
   </script>
   <!-- END switch_ticker_new -->

   <script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   $(document).ready(function(){
      <!-- BEGIN switch_enable_pm_popup -->
         pm = window.open('{U_PRIVATEMSGS_POPUP}', '_faprivmsg', 'HEIGHT=225,resizable=yes,WIDTH=400');
         pm.focus();
      <!-- END switch_enable_pm_popup -->
      <!-- BEGIN switch_report_popup -->
         report = window.open('{switch_report_popup.U_REPORT_POPUP}', '_phpbbreport', 'HEIGHT={switch_report_popup.S_HEIGHT},resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,WIDTH={switch_report_popup.S_WIDTH}');
         report.focus();
      <!-- END switch_report_popup -->
      <!-- BEGIN switch_ticker -->
         ticker_start({switch_ticker.HEIGHT}, {switch_ticker.SPACING}, {switch_ticker.SPEED}, '{switch_ticker.DIRECTION}', {switch_ticker.STOP_TIME});
      <!-- END switch_ticker -->
   });

   <!-- BEGIN switch_login_popup -->
      var logInPopUpLeft, logInPopUpTop, logInPopUpWidth = {LOGIN_POPUP_WIDTH}, logInPopUpHeight = {LOGIN_POPUP_HEIGHT}, logInBackgroundResize = false, logInBackgroundClass = false;
   <!-- END switch_login_popup -->

   <!-- BEGIN switch_login_popup -->
   $(document).ready( function() {
      $(window).resize(function() {
         var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
         var popupWidth = $("#login_popup").width();
         var mypopup = $("#login_popup");

         $("#login_popup").css({
         "left": windowWidth/2 - popupWidth/2
            });
      });
   });
   <!-- END switch_login_popup -->
   //]]>
   </script>
   {GREETING_POPUP}
   <!-- BEGIN switch_ticker_new -->
   <style>
   .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item {
      text-align:center;
      width: 10px;
   }

   .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
      margin-right: {switch_ticker.SPACING}px;
   }

   .jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-vertical {
      margin-bottom: {switch_ticker.SPACING}px;
   }
   </style>
   <!-- END switch_ticker_new -->
   {HOSTING_JS}
   <!-- BEGIN google_analytics_code -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(["_setAccount", "{G_ANALYTICS_ID}"]);
    _gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);

   <!-- BEGIN google_analytics_code_bis -->
   _gaq.push(['b._setAccount', '{G_ANALYTICS_ID_BIS}']);
   _gaq.push(['b._trackPageview']);
   <!-- END google_analytics_code_bis -->

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement("script"); ga.type = "text/javascript"; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
   //]]>
   </script>
   <!-- END google_analytics_code -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu li:first-child').attr('value', '1');
 });
  </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {
            $('#two').ContentSlider({
               width : '900px',
               height : '250px',
               speed : 500,
               easing : 'easeOutQuad',
               textResize : false
            });
         });    
</script>  

</head>

  <script>
$(function(){
   $('#pun-navlinks a')
      .css( {backgroundPosition: "0px 32px"} )
      .mouseover(function(){
         $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-0px 64px)"}, {duration:350})
      })
      .mouseout(function(){
         $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0px 32px)"}, {duration:300, complete:function(){
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: "0px 32px"})
         }})
      })

});
</script>   


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $("#vertical_slider li a").each(function(){
   $(this).hover(function(){
      $(this).animate({width: "405px"}, {queue:false, duration:450});
      },function() {
        $(this).animate({width: "128px"}, {queue:false, duration:450});
     });
    });
   /*
      To use this you need to load jquery easing plugins
   */   
    $("#vertical_slider.easing li a").each(function(){
   $(this).hover(function(){
      $(this).animate({width: "405px"}, {queue:false, duration:450, easing:'easeOutBack'});
      },function() {
        $(this).animate({width: "128px"}, {queue:false, duration:450, easing:'easeInBack'});
     });
    });   
});
</script>

<body id="top">
   <!-- BEGIN hitskin_preview -->
   <div id="hitskin_preview" style="display: block;">
      <h1><img src="http://illiweb.com/fa/hitskin/hitskin_logo.png" alt="" /> Hit<em>skin</em>.com</h1>
      <div class="content">
         <p>
            {hitskin_preview.L_THEME_SITE_PREVIEW}
            <br />
            <span>{hitskin_preview.U_INSTALL_THEME}<a href="http://{hitskin_preview.U_RETURN_THEME}">{hitskin_preview.L_RETURN_THEME}</a></span>
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- END hitskin_preview -->

   <!-- BEGIN switch_login_popup -->
   <div id="login_popup" class="module main">
      <div id="login_popup_title" class="main-head">
         <div class="h3">{SITENAME}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-content">
         {LOGIN_POPUP_MSG}
         <div id="login_popup_buttons">
            <form action="{S_LOGIN_ACTION}" method="get">
               <input type="submit" class="button2" value="{L_LOGIN}" />
               <input type="button" class="button2" value="{L_REGISTER}" onclick="parent.location='{U_REGISTER}';" />
               <input id="login_popup_close" type="button" class="button2" value="{L_DONT_DISPLAY_AGAIN}" />
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- END switch_login_popup -->

   <a id="top" name="top" accesskey="t"></a>

  <div id="header"> <div id="header-content">
               <div id="pun-intro" class="clearfix">
                  <a href="{U_INDEX}" id="pun-logo"><img src="{LOGO}" alt="{L_INDEX}" /></a>                    

                                          <div id="head-right">                                

                                          <form method="get" action="/search" id="search"><input id="search-input" type="text" name="search_keywords" maxlength="128" class="inputbox search" value="Procurar..." onclick="if (this.value == 'Procurar...') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Procurar...';" /><input id="search-button" type="submit" value="&nbsp;" /><br><a href="/search" id="advsearch" align="right" title="Busca Avançada"><img src="http://i36.servimg.com/u/f36/11/96/49/61/search15.png"/>Busca Avançada</a></form>
                                            <br/>
                                            <div id="social">

      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/MasterPublicitario" target="_blank"> <img src="http://i15.servimg.com/u/f15/18/00/02/37/f10.png" alt="Facebook"/> </a>

      <a href="https://twitter.com/MasterPublicitr" target="_blank"> <img src="http://i15.servimg.com/u/f15/18/00/02/37/t10.png" alt="Twitter"/> </a>

      <a href="http://master-publicitario.blogspot.pt/" target="_blank"> <img src="http://i71.servimg.com/u/f71/16/43/60/45/blogge10.png" alt="Blog"/> </a>

      <a href="http://master-publicitario.forumeiros.com/contact" target="_blank"> <img src="http://i71.servimg.com/u/f71/16/43/60/45/techno10.png" alt="Contacto"/> </a>

                                            </div>                                            
                                            </div>

      <div id="site-info">                      
                  <!-- BEGIN switch_h1 -->
                  <div id="pun-title">{switch_h1.MAIN_SITENAME}</div>
                  <!-- END switch_h1 -->
                  <!-- BEGIN switch_desc -->
                  <p id="pun-desc">{switch_desc.SITE_DESCRIPTION}</p>
                  <!-- END switch_desc -->
                                          </div>                                            

                                     </div>  

                                  <div id="pun-head">
                  <div id="pun-navlinks">
                                                  <div id="nav-border">
                                                  <body onload="menuSlider.init('menu','slide')">
                                                  <div class="menu">
                     <ul class="clearfix" id="menu">
                      <li>{GENERATED_NAV_BAR}</li>


                     </ul> 
                                                    <div id="slide"><!-- --></div> 
                                                    </body><
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
                                  </div>  </div>

      <div id="slider">



        <div id="two" class="contentslider">

<div class="cs_wrapper">

<div class="cs_slider">


<!-- ARTICLE --><div class="cs_article">
<h2> <a>Bem Vindo(a)</a> </h2>

<img src="http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/1476/masterra.jpg"/>
<p>

Seja Bem Vindo(a), ao fórum Master Publicitário - O teu fórum de Publicidade, aqui poderás conviver em grande e fazer novas e grandes amizades, aproveita já enquanto dura, temos um óptimo serviço de ajuda para vocês, podem divulgar a vontade e não têm problemas nenhum, não se esqueçam tudo isto é grátis.

 </p>

</div><!-- End ARTICLE -->



<!-- ARTICLE --><div class="cs_article">
<h2> <a>Regulamento </a> </h2>

<img src="http://i12.servimg.com/u/f12/18/05/64/66/master11.jpg"/>
<p>

Acabastes de chegar a este grande fórum ? Então peço que leia o nosso Regulamento, para não ser punido, sei que é chato ler mas não custa nada e ajuda sempre o fórum.

 </p>

<a href="http://master-publicitario.forumeiros.com/f10-regulamento" class="readmore">Regulamento</a>
</div><!-- End ARTICLE -->



<!-- ARTICLE --><div class="cs_article">
<h2> <a>Equipe </a> </h2>

<img src="http://i12.servimg.com/u/f12/18/05/64/66/master12.jpg"/>
<p>

Conheça a nossa equipe do fórum, e também te podes candidatar a esta grande equipe, tamos todos dispostos para o ajudar em tudo o que for necessário, não isite e ajude o fórum.

 </p>

<a href="http://master-publicitario.forumeiros.com/f12-staff" class="readmore">Equipe</a>

</div><!-- End ARTICLE -->



<!-- ARTICLE --><div class="cs_article">
<h2> <a>Publicidade </a> </h2>

<img src="http://i12.servimg.com/u/f12/18/05/64/66/master13.jpg"/>
<p>

Tens um fórum,rádio,blog,site ou outro tipo de web ? Então estás no sítio certo para divulgar sem problemas nenhum, aqui poderás divulgar o teu fórum,rádio,blog,site e muito mais e tudo isto é grátis.

</p>

<a href="http://master-publicitario.forumeiros.com/f1-publicidade" class="readmore">Publicidade</a>

</div><!-- End ARTICOL -->



</div>    <!-- End cs_slider -->  </div>  <!-- End cs_wrapper -->

</div><!-- End contentslider -->

                          </div>

     <div class="minwidth_IE">
      <div class="layout_IE">
         <div class="container_IE">

            <div class="pun">

                                             <!-- BEGIN switch_ticker_new -->
               <div id="fa_ticker_block" style="padding-top:4px;">
                  <div class="module main">
                     <div class="main-content clearfix">
                        <div id="fa_ticker_container">
                           <ul id="fa_ticker_content" class="jcarousel-skin-tango" style="display: none;width: 100%;">
                              <!-- BEGIN ticker_row -->
                              <li>{switch_ticker.ticker_row.ELEMENT}</li>
                              <!-- END ticker_row -->
                           </ul>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <!-- END switch_ticker_new -->

               <!-- BEGIN switch_ticker -->
               <div id="fa_ticker_block" style="padding-top:4px;">
                  <div class="module main">
                     <div class="main-content clearfix">
                        <div id="fa_ticker_container">
                           <div id="fa_ticker" style="height:{switch_ticker.HEIGHT}px;">
                              <div class="fa_ticker_content">
                                 <!-- BEGIN ticker_row -->
                                 <div>{switch_ticker.ticker_row.ELEMENT}</div>
                                 <!-- END ticker_row -->
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <!-- END switch_ticker -->

               <div id="page-body">
                                          <!-- BEGIN switch_user_logged_out -->
<div id="as"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-4610261741163699";
/* Brown plan */
google_ad_slot = "4261547412";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div>
<!-- END switch_user_logged_out -->
                                          <div id="{ID_CONTENT_CONTAINER}"{CLASS_CONTENT_CONTAINER}>
                     <div id="outer-wrapper">
                        <div id="wrapper">
                           <div id="container">
                              <div id="content">
                                 <div id="{ID_LEFT}">
                                    <!-- BEGIN giefmod_index1 -->
                                    {giefmod_index1.MODVAR}
                                    <!-- BEGIN saut -->
                                    <div style="height:{SPACE_ROW}px"></div>
                                    <!-- END saut -->
                                    <!-- END giefmod_index1 -->
                                 </div>
                                 <div id="main">
                                    <div id="main-content">

<!-- BEGIN html_validation -->
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
<!-- END html_validation -->
```

Caso queiram ver o "erro" ao vivo: http://master-publicitario.forumeiros.com/
A parte do sliderbar seria esta: http://prntscr.com/89m1ji

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Cara #medo de debugar isso, ta muito confuso o código, fora que tem N chamadas de javascript referenciando o evento load da página seria interessante unificar esses loads em um só e também resolver os erros de javascript, dai provavelmente vai funcionar.

Comment: O erro eu encontrei é só abrir o debug e carregar a pagina inicial o que não to encontrando é a solução rsrsrsr. brinc's vou te ajudar

Answer (score 0):

O erro em execução do script começa assim:

`TypeError: $(...).ContentSlider is not a function` na linha 46, coluna 14 abrindo o script:

```
$(function() {$('#two').ContentSlider({width : '900px',height : '250px',speed : 500,easing : 'easeOutQuad',textResize : false});});
```

esse trecho de código, não carregou o plugin que chama **ContentSlider** tem algum problema de acesso ao arquivo ou não foi feito a chamada antes desse trecho.

Comment: Eu já havia visto isso no console. Mas como resolvo?

Comment: Pelo que reparei, ContentSlider já se encontra no código, começando em: <div id="two" class="contentslider">